# The file creation/modified/ dates are changed to 12/31/4500 for attachments dragged from email in Outlook Inbox

Tags: microsoft-outlook

When I drag an attachment, pdf or DOCX or XLSX or PPTX off of an email in the Outlook inbox to either another folder or just the desktop, the created and modified dates are changed to 12/31/4500. This started a few weeks ago. Before then, I had no problem dragging things around. Only happens when dragging from the Outlook Inbox, no issues dragging out of folders into other folders. The only way to save attachments now is to use the SaveAs function on the right click menu which adds extra steps to an operation I probably do 100 or more times a day. Outlook 2016.

Anybody have any ideas what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

I tested a lot in my environment but could not reproduce your issue. What specific operations did you do before this problem occurred? Please make sure you have upgraded your Outlook and Windows to the latest version and see if the issue has any difference.

There could be some add-ins in your Outlook client that cause this issue, so it is suggested to start your Outlook in safe mode (Press Win + R, type “outlook /safe”, press Enter.) and see if the issue continues.

Comment: I am using Office 2016 and have been for years. All of a sudden a few weeks ago this started happening. I don't know that I changed anything. Now whenever I get an email with an attachment and I just drag it off the email to the desktop the date changes to 12/31/4500. Windows is the latest version but I am on Office 2016. I've disabled all the addins and it still happens. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a patch that is supposed to fix the issue (I have the same issue but I am waiting for our IT department to vet the patch before applying it, so I don't know if it resolves the issue).

https://support.microsoft.com/en-ae/help/4484343/may-5-2020-update-for-outlook-2016-kb4484343

Comment: I got the green light from my IT department. I tried to install the patch but it said it was already installed.

Comment: Thank you Marcus for taking a shot at this for me. I just tried to run the update and got the same message that the update was already installed. So back to the drawing boards I guess. Thank you again for trying.

Comment: I put in a help ticket with my IT department, and they actually suggested uninstalling the update (requires a reboot), and that actually fixed it for me. They weren't sure if our patching system will try to automatically reinstall it, so he is leaving my ticket open for a few days to see what happens and if it breaks again.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll give it a shot tomorrow.

Comment: So unfortunately the issue returned for me. The patch didn't get (directly) reinstalled, but my IT support guys suspect that the May 5 patch I linked may have gotten incorporated into the May 10 patch for Outlook that they deployed, since other systems said the patch was already installed when it wasn't on the list.

As another point of info, the issue only happens to me when the email is either digitally signed, encrypted, or both. We use Entrust as our encryption/signing platform. I believe my IT dept has escalated the issue with Microsoft.

Comment: thank you for the report. I tried to install the patch and it reported already installed. So I went to the installed list to try and remove it per your previous post, and I could not find it in the installed list. Very puzzling and very buggy software. We don't use any encryption or digital signatures. My IT department is incompetent anyhow.

Comment: I'm afraid this issue might be related to the Outlook or Windows version. I did some research but cannot find any official documents explaining this issue. Please keep an eye on the announcement or update from Microsoft. Hope this issue can be resolved soon.